# SQL Server query - how to write multiple item search for table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to write query for this scenario: there is `Product` table & on UI side, there are multiple filter conditions e.g. Color, Name, ProductNumber, Size, etc., with multi select facility for each of the filter. Use can select any combination of this filter or can't select a filter.

How to write a SQL query for this scenario?

This is what I tried:

```
-- these variables contains comma delimited string of multiple values
declare @color varchar(max), 
        @pnumber varchar(max),
        @name varchar(max),
        @size varchar(max)

        @searchFilter table
        (
            searchType varchar(max)
            ID int,
            value varchar(max)
        )

-- I am parsing these filter values & putting in a table variable @searchFilter

Select * 
from Product
where 
     (@color is null or Color in (select value from @searchFilter 
                                  where searchType = 'Color'))
     and
     (@name is null or Name in (select value from @searchFilter 
                                where searchType = 'Name'))
     and
     (@size is null or Size in (select value from @searchFilter 
                                where searchType = 'Size'))
     and
     (@pnumber is null or ProductNumber in (select value from @searchFilter 
                                            where searchType = 'PNumber'))
```

I am getting error

> Conversion failed to convert value 'xx' into datatype int

1. How to write query efficiently for this case?
2. Is the above query the right way to write this code?

Comment: ProductNumber is int, and you're trying to use varchar field value for it? Is id supposed to be used instead?

Comment: The performance problem with your query is that it has all the "or xxx is null" parts. Read this blog post http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ you can use similar way for this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error seems to be due to one of the search fields (likely `Size` or `ProductNumber`) being int, and the `value` field you got from the `@searchFilter` table is varchar(MAX).